# C# code for login not working

Tags: c#

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        string readHtml = webClient.DownloadString("http://yourdomain.com/yourfolder/vars.txt");
        string line = "";
        while ((line == webClient.readHtml()) != null)
        {
            string[] components = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            users.Add(components[0]);
            pass.Add(components[1]);
        }

        TimeLabel.Text = (DateTime.Now.ToString() + " System time at load");
        Text = "Admin Login";
    }
```

This code will grab usernames and passwords from a text file and in next if (not shown here) will check it if the login is same as in the file....

Comment: So.... are we to guess what is not working?

Comment: yes i don't know any fixes

Comment: You have to tell us how it isn't working.  Are you getting an error?  Have you stepped through the method with a debugger?

Comment: the webclient.readHtml() https://ctrlv.cz/H7nk <--- screenshot 

Sorry I don't have English version of visual studio

Comment: The `WebClient` class does not have a `readHtml()` method (which is what the error is telling you) - and even if it did it would be written with a capital `R` (because that is the naming convention for C#). So it's unclear what you expect that method to do or where it's supposed to come from. My best guess is that you want to do *something* with the `readHtml` string variable you have, but I don't know what, because `(line == readHtml) != null` doesn't make much sense either

Answer (score 0):

```
string line = "";
while ((line == webClient.readHtml()) != null)
```

strongly looks like code reading lines from a StreamReader for example, that reads in one line each time.

`WebClient.DownloadString(string)` however reads in the whole file into one string. So you gotta do something like this to get the single lines

```
string[] splt=readHtml.Split('\n');//or different presentation of line break
for(int i=0; i<splt.Length; i++){
    //split your components from splt[i] here
    //and add them to your attributes or whatever
}
```